# AWK - calculate highest sales from arrays

Tags: arrays, math, awk

Under the sales lines, my second if to calculate highest sales aren't getting the final highest sale amount. It is off by one sales transaction coming out as 6999.99 instead of  7226.98. Not sure how or why this would happen given how straightforward the code is. any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
BEGIN{
    ## Field Separator.
    FS=":";

    ##Declaration
    highSales = 0;

    ## Header.
    print
    printf("%s\n", "ABC Computing");
    printf("%s\n", "2017 Sales Associates Report");
    printf("%-30s %-20s %20s\n", "Name", "Position", "Sales amount");

    for (i = 0; i < 72; i++)
    {
    printf("%c", "=");
    }

    print;
 }

 ## Associates lines.
 ## $1 -> Associate ID.
 ## $2 -> First name.
 ## $3 -> Position.
 NF == 3{
    salesPersonID[$1] = $2;
    position[$1] = $3;
 }

 ## Product lines.
 ## $1 -> Product ID.
 ## $4 -> Price.
 NF == 4{
    product[$1] = $4;
 }

 ## Sales lines.
 ## $2 -> Product ID.
 ## $3 -> Quantity.
 ## $4 -> Date.
 NF == 5 && $4 ~ /2017/{
    if ($2 in product){
            sales[$5] += $3 * product[$2];

            if  ( ($3 * product[$2]) > highSales){
                    highSalesID = salesPersonID[$5];
                    highSales = $3 * product[$2];
            }
    }

 }

 END{
    for (z in salesPersonID)
    {
            printf("%-30s %-20s %20s\n", salesPersonID[z], position[z], sales[z]);
    }
    print "\n" highSalesID " has the highest sales total with: " highSales "\n";

    printf("%s\n", "Sorted Sales Report");

    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
    printf("%c", "=");
    }

    print "\n"

    for(x in sales)
    {
            printf("%-2s %-30s %20s\n", x, salesPersonID[x], sales[x]) | "sort -rnk4";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As you've put it now, this question is not entirely clear in its aim. Please limit a question to one problem and show the symptoms of the problem you are facing as well as the desired result of the problematic code. This will help people better address your problem and help you find a solution.

Comment: This is 100% awk code -- nothing about it is specific to Linux.

Comment: `sort -k3nr`, you don't have a fourth field.

Comment: Thanks karakfa, that will help but my main issue is still with the highSales not being the correct amount.